# How can i use bower installed Javascript files?

Tags: node.js, bower, mean.io

I am currently using Mean.IO. I have read that to install css or javascript I can use bower. After using bower install  I can see the downloaded files inside bower_components but I am not sure how can I access it inside my views?

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose a route to `bower_components`.

`app.use(express.static("vendor", __dirname + "/bower_components"));`

You can access the files in that directory from your HTML file using the prefix `bower_components`.

For example:

`<script src="/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />`

Answer (score 0):

Reference them with normal `<script>` or `<link>` tags in your template(s). In many angular applications this would be in `index.html`.

This is the easiest way to get started. Some tools like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) will update your templates for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
bower install bootstrap
```

in a public folder then it will be served under

```
/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
```